# Python: Generating a multivalued truth table of 5 columns, where each column can take a certain set of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

The problem is probably simpler than I make it sound. Heard of 2 value truth table with 3 columns having a total of 8 values? `TTT, TTF...` and 2 value truth table with 2 columns having 4 values? `TT, TF, FF, FT`

In my problem:

There are 5 columns.

`A, B, C, D, E`

Column `A` can take only `1` value: `a`

Column `B` can take `2` values:  `x` and `y`

Column `C` can take `3` values `1`, `2` and `3`, (The value can be string or integer, the datatype doesn't matter.

Column `D` can take `2` values `t` and `f`
and finally

Column `E` can take `3` values `alpha` and `omega` and `beta`

So there will be a total of 36 combinations! `(1 X 2 X 3 X 2 X 3)` = `36`

What have I done so far?

I've come up with this abomination.. **The output I desire is produced by running this below:**

```
col1 = ['a']
col2 = ['x', 'y']
col3 = ['1', '2', '3']
col4 = ['t', 'f']
col5 = ['alpha', 'omega', 'beta']

for i in col1:
    for j in col2:
        for k in col3:
            for l in col4:
                for m in col5:
                    print(i, j, k, l, m)
```

The 36 rows..

```
a x 1 t alpha
a x 1 t omega
a x 1 t beta
a x 1 f alpha
a x 1 f omega
a x 1 f beta
a x 2 t alpha
a x 2 t omega
a x 2 t beta
a x 2 f alpha
a x 2 f omega
a x 2 f beta
a x 3 t alpha
a x 3 t omega
a x 3 t beta
a x 3 f alpha
a x 3 f omega
a x 3 f beta
a y 1 t alpha
a y 1 t omega
a y 1 t beta
a y 1 f alpha
a y 1 f omega
a y 1 f beta
a y 2 t alpha
a y 2 t omega
a y 2 t beta
a y 2 f alpha
a y 2 f omega
a y 2 f beta
a y 3 t alpha
a y 3 t omega
a y 3 t beta
a y 3 f alpha
a y 3 f omega
a y 3 f beta
```

I'm not sure if there is any easier, less verbose way to do this.. I'm wondering if there is..

I'm okay with the 36 rows being returned as a `list` of `lists` or a `pandas DataFrame` or a `numpy array` that I can iterate over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use product from itertools to give you list a tuples:

Input:

```
import itertools
lst = [['a'],['x', 'y'],['1', '2', '3'],['t', 'f'],['alpha', 'omega', 'beta']]
list(itertools.product(*lst))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'x', '1', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '1', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '1', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'x', '1', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '1', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '1', 'f', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '2', 'f', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'x', '3', 'f', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '1', 'f', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '2', 'f', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 't', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 't', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 't', 'beta'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 'f', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 'f', 'omega'),
 ('a', 'y', '3', 'f', 'beta')]
```